# can't download file from asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, attachment

I have an asp.net application that writes some physical files in a folder of the server.

While I work in my test environment I can download the files clicking on the dynamical links, but after I deployed the application I can't download the files anymore.

I'm getting the standard - `The page cannot be found error page`.

Also I can download the file after I add an extension, like this 
`server/TempFiles/1b008aaa-47ad-4fd7-b95d-05ef81a1785c.txt`
but downloading the file without "**.txt**" is not possible.

How to repair this behavior?

Comment: What page cannot be found? What are you trying to download?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamical links"?

Comment: I'm trying to download file "1b008aaa-47ad-4fd7-b95d-05ef81a1785c" and I get a page -The page cannot be found - as a response instead of download dialog.

Comment: what file is 1b008aaa-47ad-4fd7-b95d-05ef81a1785c???

Comment: 1b008aaa-47ad-4fd7-b95d-05ef81a1785c -  is the file name. I generate the file name as a random guid.

Answer (score 1):

IIS doesn't know how to serve up files without extensions this is why it treated it as a link and looked for a page or directory with that name, to which it couldn't find one.  I'm not an IIS guru but you may be able to configure IIS to serve up those files, but you will have to treat them as some type I would imagine.